# how to make data type integer in python

Tags: python, csv, scikit-learn, floating-point, integer

i wan to cluster data using hierarchical clustering and i want the result will be data type is integer not float

```
import pandas as pd
import csv
#import csv
#from nltk.cluster import KMeansClusterer, euclidean_distance
dataset =pd.read_csv('vector.csv')
X = dataset
from sklearn.cluster import AgglomerativeClustering

cluster = AgglomerativeClustering(n_clusters=5, affinity='euclidean', linkage='ward')
cluster.fit_predict(X)
#print(cluster.labels_)
file=open('data_hirarki/hirarki.csv','a')
tulis=csv.writer(file,delimiter='\n',lineterminator='\n')
tulis.writerows([cluster.labels_])
file.close()
```

how can i do?

the result like

```
1.0, 2.0, etc
```

i want 1, 2,3

Answer (score 1):

use list comprehension:

```py
int_labels = [int(label) for label in cluster.labels_]
```